# Best way to track the previous node in my sortedLinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

My professor in my CS class asked me to sort a LinkedList. The method I am trying to use to sort the linkedlist is to do so whenever a new int is added to the linked list. The meat of the problem is that the method he recommended I use to sort the linkedlist requires me to somehow track what the previous element in the linked list was, despite the fact that it is a Singly linked list and not a double linked list. I made sure to ask him whether he wanted me to create a doubly linked list or not and he said that wasn't what he was talking about. The biggest hurdle is that on the 2nd else-if code block inside my add function, where  do this code here:

```
if ((int) input < (int) current.value){
                   LinkedListNode newnode = new LinkedListNode(input, current);
```

I'm not sure how to track the previous. What would be the best way to do so?

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {

  private LinkedListNode head;

  SortedLinkedList() {
    head = null;
  }

  // Start from head
  // Check its value
  // 2 nodes at once
  // Check previous node
  // Check next node
  // Check after head before end
  // Check last element

  public synchronized void add(T input) {

    LinkedListNode current;

    if (head == null) {

      LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(input, null);
      head = newNode;
      head.setIndex(0);

    } else if ((int) input < (int) head.value) {

      current = head;

      LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(input, null);
      head = newNode;

      newNode.setNext(current);
    } else if ((int) input > (int) head.value) {
      current = head;

      while (current.getNext() != null) {

        if ((int) input < (int) current.value) {
          LinkedListNode newnode = new LinkedListNode(input, current);
        }

        current = current.getNext();
      }

    } else {

      current = head;
      int indexCounter = head.index;
      while (current.getNext() != null) {

        current = current.getNext();
        indexCounter++;

        int currentgetNEXTHOLDER;
        int currentValueHolder;

        // Loops through the functuon and switches any values less than the previous

        if ((int) current.getNext().value < (int) current.value) {
          currentgetNEXTHOLDER = (int) current.getNext().value;
          currentValueHolder = (int) current.value;

          current.getNext().value = currentValueHolder;
          current.value = currentgetNEXTHOLDER;
        }
      }

      current.setIndex(indexCounter);
      LinkedListNode mynewNode = new LinkedListNode(input, null);
      current.setNext(mynewNode);
    }
  }

  public T getValue(int index) {

    T keeptheValue = null;
    LinkedListNode current = getHead();

    while (current.getNext() != null) {
      if (current.index == index) {
        keeptheValue = (T) current.value;
      }

      current = current.getNext();
    }

    return keeptheValue;
  }

  public Boolean search(T value) {
    LinkedListNode current = getHead();
    boolean isitThere = false;
    while (current.getNext() != null) {
      if (current.value == value) {
        isitThere = true;
      }
    }
    return isitThere;
  }

  public LinkedListNode getHead() {
    return head;
  }

  public String printAllValues() {
    LinkedListNode current = head;
    String intTOStringchain = "";
    while (current.getNext() != null) {

      intTOStringchain = intTOStringchain + "," + Integer.toString((int) current.value);
    }

    return intTOStringchain;
  }

  class LinkedListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public T value;
    private LinkedListNode next;
    public int index;
    public LinkedListNode previous;

    public LinkedListNode(T value, LinkedListNode next) {
      this.value = value;
      this.next = next;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext() {
      return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode next) {
      this.next = next;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getPrevious() {
      return previous;
    }

    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode previous) {
      this.previous = previous;
    }

    public boolean greaterThan(T otherValue) {

      int definingValue = otherValue.compareTo(value);
      if (definingValue > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
      this.index = index;
    }
  }
}
```

Above is all the code in the class, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just have a variable pointing to the previous element of the list, and update it to the "current" one when you move forwards.

Comment: `The meat of the problem is that the method he recommended I use to sort the linkedlist requires me to somehow track what the previous element in the linked list was, despite the fact that it is a Singly linked list and not  a double linked list. ` - what have you created `LinkedListNode previous` for? Why do you have the instance variables in `class LinkedListNode` declared as `public`?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code for add method:

```
prev = null
curr = head
while curr != null and curr.value <= value:
    prev = curr
    curr = curr.next
if prev == null then:
    head = new Node(value, curr)
else:
    prev.next = new Node(value, curr)
```

Your code is over-complicated. It's really just that simple.

Comment: I don't really understand how this sorts the linked list, could you walk me through the logic?Sorry, I'm a bit slow.

Comment: @A.JD `prev` refers to the node before `curr`. If list is empty, they are both null. If `curr` is on first node, `prev` is null. Keep looping through the nodes until `curr.value > value` or end of list (`curr` is null), at which point we insert new node before `curr`, i.e. after `prev`.

Answer (score 0):

*if Your list is derived from* `java.util.List`

```
int idx = Collections.binarySearch( list, valueToAdd );
if( idx < 0 )
  idx = -idx - 1;
list.add( idx, valueToAdd );
```

if You are adding all elements with the above method, all elements in the list will be sorted